# Excel 2016 VBA - Problems upgrading from Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

I developed several userforms and macros for a project in Excel 2013, but when I try to test them in Excel 2016, I get multiple errors on basic VBA functions.

For example I get an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error from the following code:

```
Private Sub ShowImpact()
FormImpact.Show
End Sub
```

Another example, the following code gives me an error "Can't find project or library" on the [RIMS_tbl] table reference. This is a named table in the document:

```
With FormImpact.cboIndustry
    .ColumnCount = 11
    .ColumnWidths = "0;50;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"
    .RowSource = "=RIMS!" & [RIMS_tbl].Address
    .BoundColumn = 1
    .TextColumn = 2
End With
```

As another example, I get the same error message on "Format" method in the following code:

```
Private Sub txtConLand_AfterUpdate()
txtConLand = Format(txtConLand.Value, "#,##0")
End Sub
```

Lastly, I have a label that I'm using as a background on the form, which works fine in Excel 2013, but for some reason it covers all of the other controls in 2016, and I can't send it to the back.

I'm really hoping that there is some setting in 2016 that will fix all of these problems, because I can't figure out why so many things would break between these two versions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any "missing" references in your VB Project ?

Comment: As @TimWilliams says check your references.  Click in the menue _tools_ and then _references_. It should be the same and none of them should be marked as MISSING

Comment: Yes, there is a missing reference to "ATLEntityPicker 1.0 Type Library." I unchecked that in the Excel template, and it seems to have fixed most of the problems! Thank you both @TimWilliams and Stefan. I'm still having a problem with the background label covering up the rest of the userform. If you have any suggestions on that, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, the solution to this problem was in eliminating missing references between different version numbers. In the Visual Basic interface, go to Tools->References. Check for missing references in all versions supported. Thanks @TimWilliams and @Stefan for the solution to this problem.

I never did figure out how to fix the problem of the z-order for the background label. Even setting the v-order for that label programmatically didn't work. But I did come up with a workaround. First I made a small white bitmap file. Then under the page settings, I set the background picture to be the bitmap file. Then I set set the "PictureSizeMode" property "fmPictureSizeModeStretch," which stretched the bitmap to fit the entire page. Finally, I added a border around the entire form.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when migrating an VBA powered Excel from Excel 2010 to 2016. Deselecting the **ATLEntityPicker 1.0 Type Library** from the References list solved it.